# Example of Jenkins Plot Plugin input files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for some examples of properties/ csv file which act as input for the Plot Plugin on Jenkins. I have tried to search a lot, but didn't find any example as such which shows a clear example of how the plot plugin expects the input file format.

Answer (score 6):

An example of a csv file (`example.csv`) could be the following:

```
data1,data2,total,threshold_total
100,201,301,500
```

In Jenkins you would configure the plot using `example.csv` as Data series file. Choosing `Load data from csv file` you can decide which columns to include or exclude. For example, if you choose `Include columns by name` and as CSV Exclusion values `total,threshold_total` a plot showing the `total` and `threshold_total` values will be produced.